# Socket.io: "cannot read property 'emit' of undefined"

Tags: android, socket.io, couchdb

I want to send some Data to my Android device which is connected to my Nodejs Server. But i get an "cannot read property 'emit' of undefined" error, when i am emitting the event.

The server:

```
var nano = require('nano')('http://admin:1234@localhost:5984');
var gpsdata = nano.db.use('gpsdata');

const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
 console.log('a user connected');
 socket.on('new message', function incoming(message) {
    gpsdata.list(function (err, body)
    {
       var current_number_of_tracks = body.total_rows + 1;
       console.log(current_number_of_tracks);
       gpsdata.insert({name: 'Route ' + current_number_of_tracks, message}, null, function(err, body) {
          if (!err){
          console.log(body);
          }
       });
    });
    console.log('received: %s', message);
 });
 socket.on('getdata', function(socket){
   gpsdata.view('test', 'new-view', function(err, body){
     if(!err)
     {
        body.rows.forEach(function(doc){
           console.log(doc.value);
           socket.emit('getRouteNames', doc.value); //Causes Error
        });
     }
   });
 });
 socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
 });
});
server.listen(3000);
```

Client:

```
    mSocket.on("getRouteNames", new Emitter.Listener() {
        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            routeNames.add(args);
        }
    });
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined

```
C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\index.js:31
          socket.emit('getRouteNames', doc.value).bind(socket);
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'emit' of undefined
    at C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\index.js:31:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\index.js:29:19
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\node_module\nano\lib\nano.js
:121:11)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\node_modules\request\request.js:1161:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Pavel\.atom\ws2\node_modules\request\request.js:1083:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
```

Comment: What is the stack trace? Hypothesis: There might be a problem with the "this" binding inside the socket.emit function.  what if you do `socket.emit(...).bind(socket);`

Comment: It causes the same Error. I will edit my post with the exact Errormsg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I just overwrite Socket in:

```
socket.on('getdata', function(socket)
```